# Ideals, quotients and equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So, let $A=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $ I=\{(X^2+X+1)P | P \in A \}$ 
I succeeded showing that this is the ideal, but now i have to find $A/I$, show that it have only 4 classes and find to what class corresponds elements like $X^3+X^2$ and $X^2+1$. I have some problems understanding the quotient groups. Mainly I considered looking at the wiki's [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) on quotients but there was sets and I arrived to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64984/question-about-wikipedia-coset-quotient-group-example).

It's very easy intuitevely follow that quotient is just mod n. But I dont understand the idea how to arrive to such result from having that $G/H=\{ xH | x \in G \}$.

Comment: For rings, $G/H=\{H+x|x\in G\}$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what sort of problems you have understanding quotient structures. It's difficult to answer that part of your query without knowing more precisely what the problems are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Use the Division Algorithm to write $\rm\:f(x) = (x^2+x+1)\:q(x) + r(x),\ deg\ r \le 1.\:$ Thus, mod $\rm I = (x^2+x+1),\:$ every $\rm\:f(x)\in \mathbb F_2[x]\:$ is equivalent to a linear polynomial (degree $\le 1).\:$ Further, distinct linear polynomials are inequivalent mod I, else their difference would be a linear polynomial $\ne 0$  divisible by $\rm\:x^2 + x + 1.$ Thus the linear polynomials $\rm\: a\:x + b,\ a,b\in \mathbb F_2,\:$ are a complete system of representatives of the equivalence classes (cosets) of the quotient ring$\rm\:A/I.$

Comment: Thus, mod I = (x^2+x+1), every $\rm\:f(x)\in \mathbb F_2[x]\:$ is equivalent to a linear polynomial (i.e. degree $\le 1)\:$
Cant understand this line.. Why?

Comment: Modulo $\rm\:(g),\ \ g\:\equiv\: 0\ \Rightarrow\ g\:q + r\:\equiv\: 0\cdot q + r\:\equiv\: r.\:$ Above $\rm\: g = x^2+x+1.\:$ Such polynomial congruence arithmetic is analogous to congruence arithmetic of integers mod $\rm\:m\:$. Both cases employ the Euclidean Algorithm to reduce elements to their "smaller" normal-form representatives.

Comment: As far as i can get $A$ is any polynomial of degree $n$. $I$ is the same polynomials but multiplied by $(X^2+X+1)$? Zero class will be equal to class of $X^2+X+1$ so we have left $1$, $X$, $X+1$ ?

Comment: $A = \mathbb F_2[x]$ is the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in the field of two elements. $I$ is the prinicpal ideal $(g) = g A$ of all multiples of $g = x^2+x+1$. Yes, those four classes form a complete system of reps of $A/I$, by the reasoning in the above answer.